# How to check for Boolean condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have `Alcohol_df` dataframe in which qualification is a column.

I have created a list as follows:

```
Graduate_list=['B.tech','b.tech','b-tech','Btech','BE',
               'B.E', 'b.e','BACHELOR','bachelor','BSc',
               'Bsc','bsc','BSC','BBM']
```

I did

```
Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list)
```

to find which columns contains the elements from the list.

I want to do some operation on the dataframe if its value is in the list.I did

```
if ((Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list)):
```

But getting this error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Kindly help me solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) (return `True` if at least one value is `True`) or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) (return `True` if all values are `True`s) for return scalar, because else it return `boolean Series`:

```
if (Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list).any()):
```

Sample:

```
Alcohol_df = pd.DataFrame({'qualification':['B.tech','a','Btech'],
                           'B':[4,5,6]})

print (Alcohol_df)
   B qualification
0  4        B.tech
1  5             a
2  6         Btech

print (Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list))
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: qualification, dtype: bool

if (Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list).any()):
    print ('bingo')
```

If need select `DataFrame` by `boolean Series` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = Alcohol_df[Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list)]
print (df1)
   B qualification
0  4        B.tech
2  6         Btech
```

Comment: If I use if (Alcohol_df['qualification'].isin(Graduate_list).any()): all values in the qualification column are getting changed even it is not present in Graduate_list. I am trying to do like this for i in range(len(Alcohol_df['qualification'])):
    if (Alcohol_df['qualification'][i].isin(Graduate_list).all()):
        Alcohol_df['qualification'][i]=Alcohol_df['qualification'][i].replace(to_replace=Alcohol_df['qualification'][i],value='Graduate') I am getting this error AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'isin'

Plz help me

Comment: I think the best is, if create some small data sample be free edit `Alcohol_df = pd.DataFrame({'qualification':['B.tech','a','Btech'],
                           'B':[4,5,6]})

print (Alcohol_df)` and add desired output. I believe I find solution for you.