# How do I create a for loop here?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to take names from a name list, look those up in an excel sheet, and return both the name and a value in another column (column 'Unnamed: 4'). This is what I have right now, and it works to lookup one name, but I want to look up every name in the list. How do I make a for loop here?

```
file = '/mnt/c/python/Iban programmatje/testsheet.xlsx'

f = open('namelist.txt', 'r')
namestring = f.read()
f.close()

namelist = namestring.split(",")

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

row = df[df['Unnamed: 3'].str.contains(namelist[0])]
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for Boolean condition in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43582154/how-to-check-for-boolean-condition-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Hi, maybe convert the list into pandas dataframe and join it to the excel df.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much context but i guess it would be something like this: A for loop for the names and a list 'rows' to store the results

```
file = '/mnt/c/python/Iban programmatje/testsheet.xlsx'

f = open('namelist.txt', 'r')
namestring = f.read()
f.close()

namelist = namestring.split(",")

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

rows = []
for name in namelist:
    rows.append(df[df['Unnamed: 3'].str.contains(name)])

for row in rows:
    .....
```